# Form doesn't save: doesn't seem to pass on parent_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that includes two models, one of which is nested in another. When on the development server I submit the form, the submission generates the flash error message:

```
The form contains 1 error: 
* Members organization can't be blank
```

Each Member belongs to 1 Organization. Might the error have to do with that the organization isn't saved yet when it's trying to save the Member (for a new organization, it's supposed to simulateneously save the organization and member)? Should I add code that sets organization_id for the member (but I would expect `@organization.members.build` to take care of that)? What am I doing wrong here?

The **server log**:

```
Processing by OrganizationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "organization"=>{"org_name"=>"sadfsdaf", "phone"=>"sdfds", "members_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"username"=>"fsfdsfsad", "email"=>"sfdsdf@sfsdf.com", "fullname"=>"sdfds", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}, "admin"=>"true", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.5ms)  begin transaction
  Member Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE LOWER("members"."email") = LOWER('sfdsdf@sfsdf.com') LIMIT 1
  Member Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "members" WHERE LOWER("members"."username") = LOWER('fsfdsfsad') LIMIT 1
  Organization Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."org_name") = LOWER('sadfsdaf') LIMIT 1
  Organization Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."phone") = LOWER('sdfds') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.9ms)
```

---

**Organization model:**

```
has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

**Member model:**

```
belongs_to :organization

validates :organization_id, presence: true  # There are other validations as well, but I don't think they matter for this question.

def send_activation_email
  MemberMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
end
```

**Organization controller:**

```
def new
  @organization = Organization.new
  @member = @organization.members.build
end

def create
  @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
  if @organization.save
    @member.send_activation_email  # Method in Member model file.
    flash[:success] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else                          
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
def organizationnew_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:org_name,
                                      :phone,
                   member_attributes: [:email,
                                      :username,
                                      :admin,
                                      :password,
                                      :password_confirmation
                                      ])
end
```

**New view:**

```
<%= form_for(@organization) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :org_name, %>
  <%= f.text_field :phone %>

  <%= f.fields_for :members do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_field :username %>
    <%= p.email_field :email %>
    <%= p.password_field :password %>
    <%= p.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :admin, true %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "formbutton btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try by removing your validation in member model 'validates :organization_id, presence: true'

Comment: If I remove the validation and also don’t include the line in `def create` that defines the @member (as suggested in other answer), then the form saves the organization and member correctly. In fact, it even saves the organization_id for the member and thus recognizes the relationship, as it should. What does this mean? Because I of course need the model validation included… but when I put it back the form doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the permitted params, try changing `member_attributes` to `members_attributes`. Also on the create action You are referring to `@member` but its not defined yet.

To debug further more replace your create action with:

```
def create
  return render text: organizationnew_params
end
```

This way, when you send the form you will get all the permitted params and check if it's what you expected.

To Send the emails replace

```
@member.send_activation_email
```

With

```
@organization.members.each do |single_member|
  single_member.send_activation_email
end
```

#### 3rd Edit

Just use this

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params)
  if @organization.save
    @organization.members.each do |single_member|
      single_member.send_activation_email
    end
    flash[:success] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    redirect_to root_url
  else                          
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def organizationnew_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:org_name,
                                      :phone,
                   members_attributes: [:id,:email,
                                      :username,
                                      :admin,
                                      :password,
                                      :password_confirmation
                                      ])
end
```

#### 4th Edit

### The validation:

When creating `members` with `oraganization` ( in the `OraganizationsController` ), you do not need to validate `organization_id` because it will be created at the same time of the `organization`. Unfortunately you will need the validation of the `organization_id` when adding a new `member` to the `organization`. So what we can do is add a condition to the validation:

```
#member.rb
attr_accessor :require_organization_id
belongs_to :organization

validates :organization_id, presence: true, if: :require_organization_id
```

#### How to use it:

```
member = Member.new(name: "Some Name")
member.valid? #true
member.require_organization_id = true
member.valid? #false
member.organization = Organization.first
member.valid? #true
```

Comment: I changed the params to `members_attributes`. After this, nothing changed, still same error.  I've kept this change in my code.

Comment: Next I added the line `@member = @organization.members.build(organizationnew_params)` to `def create` in the controller, as to define @member. However, then on submission I get the error message `unknown attribute 'org_name' for Member`, referring to the newly added line.

Comment: As an example I used https://github.com/railscasts/416-form-objects/tree/master/signup-before (which is not completely similar as for the 1:1 relationship they have they can use build_ method). There they don't define @member (or in their case @profile) either in `def create`, so I'm not completely sure this is necessary.  Cf: https://github.com/railscasts/416-form-objects/blob/master/signup-before/app/controllers/users_controller.rb

Comment: I replaced the `def create` as you suggested and on form submission got: `{"org_name"=>"sadfsdaf", "phone"=>"sdfds", "members_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"sfsa@sfsd.com", "username"=>"fsfdsfsad", "fullname"=>"sdfds", "password"=>"foobar", "password_confirmation"=>"foobar"}}}`  

This is what I would expect. When the member is created it also requires organization_id. But I wouldn’t expect this here (and its not included in the params) as I would expect the create action to create the relationship and thereby the correct organization_id itself.

Comment: I replaced the line that sends the emails as you suggested. The error message remains the same: `unknown attribute 'org_name' for Member` if I include the line that defines @member in `def create`. And `Members organization can't be blank` otherwise.

Comment: Please paste the full error stack `unknown attribute 'org_name' for Member`

Comment: Full error stack below. But this error is only there when the @member line is included. I simply think this line should be left out (also see the other answer: the form works without this line IF I also leave out the validation in the member model (which I don’t think I should do).

Comment: Full error: `unknown attribute 'org_name' for Member. 
Extracted source (around line #26): 
24  def create 
25    @organization = Organization.new(organizationnew_params) 
26    @member = @organization.members.build(organizationnew_params) 
27    if @organization.save 
28      @organization.members.each do |single_member| 
29        single_member.send_activation_email `

Comment: I've reedited the answer , check if it works this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76642/discussion-between-marwen-and-nick).

Comment: add this :
## member.rb 
`belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :members`
## organization.rb 
`has_many :members, inverse_of: :organization`
add these lines and test it with the validation

Comment: This still produced the error `Members organization can't be blank`.

Comment: If you didn't find a solution, you can check the edit in the answer, I've added one solution to handle the validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you set validation in member model i.e.

```
validates :organization_id, presence: true
```

then it looks in member params for organization_id which doesn't present in params of memeber

```
"members_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"sfsa@sfsd.com", "username"=>"fsfdsfsad", "fullname"=>"sdfds", "password"=>"foobar", "password_confirmation"=>"foobar"}}
```

thats why its showing validation error so remove this line

```
validates :organization_id, presence: true
```

from your member model

Also for @member issue you need to do like this

```
@organization.memebers.each do |member|
  member.send_activation_email
end
```

Comment: The form indeed functions if I remove the member model validation. But I definitely need to keep the validation, otherwise the model wouldn't be safe. So is there no way around it? Should I perhaps adjust the params to include organization_id? If yes, but wouldn't that be unsafe in that this would allow a hacker to use the form to create a member for an already existing organization?

Comment: What safety you want? If want that member must contain organization id than it is done by rails its self.

Comment: I don't know much about the topic, but how I understand it you need client-side and server-side protection. Without the model validation you loose server-side protection, which would enable a hacker to use for example SQL injection and enter members without an organization?